# How do Displacer Beasts' life cycle and reproduction work?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

So I am building a village and I decided to give them a displacer beast problem that has existed for the villages entire history; however, upon doing research I can't find basic information about them such as natural lifespans. Looking into other monsters and beasts, I run into the same problem.

I want to try and build a realistic problem for this village and I need to know for example:

- How many baby displacer beasts per pregnancy?
- How do their mating cycles work?
- What are the natural lifespans for them?
- Do displacer beasts have dens? If not, what kind of shelter do they prefer?

I notice this same problem occurs for most if not all non-player races in D&D. While this question is focused on Displacer Beasts, information about a resource that covers more would be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found some information on an article in Dragon Magazine #109 called [*The Ecology of the Displacer Beast.*](https://annarchive.com/files/Drmg109.pdf)

It gives some answers, but based on a one-time occurrence, so I guess you can do what you want. I don't think the people who create monsters for D&D give much thought about their lifecycle because those monsters are supposed to be slain by the players, not studied in detail...

To answer your questions, based on this article:

- One to four cubs,
- Male/female pairings, the cubs are raised by both parents, not much else is known,
- Cubs leave the lair for the first time at four months, they are adult at about two years old, and they might be able to live to be 100 years old,
- They do live in dens/caves.

Comment: @KaleDodge: Regarding your broader question of where you can find such info about monsters: as Sava points out, it leaves most such questions unanswered, though you might find some of that info in books for previous editions. In general, it's up to you as DM to fill in the gaps however you want or however makes the best sense for your story.

Comment: @V2Blast As you mention, previous books could have the information I seek, hence why I posted my question here. I wanted to try and make this problem seem realistic rather than too small of a problem to be not worth mentioning but not too large of a problem that the town would be overwhelmed without the parties intervention since they had been dealing with this problem for their entire history. I'm the type of DM who enjoys doing the math and figuring out how to make what I present to my players be both enjoyable for them and also make practical objective sense for what the situation is